# Functions constantly returns a '0'

Tags: excel, excel-2010

`A1` = `317.84`, `B1` = `422.79`.
Cell `A1` and `B1` performs a `SUM` on couple of numbers that are calculated through basic math operators and a `ROUND` function.

Calling the following function in a nearby cell:
`=SQRT(A1*A1+B1*B1)` constantly yields a `0`.
**Edit**: this actually applies to any function that contains any of those two cells

Now this problem is reproducible but clearly doesn't make any sense.

#### Some Information That Might Help

- Working on `Excel 2010`
- I did add some `VBA` code but it has nothing to do with the functions
- A download link of the file:

  - http://speedy.sh/QaZ7Z/.xlsm
  - http://speedy.sh/bfMZM/.xlsx

See cells BY35:BW35

Any ideas what might lead to that?

Comment: Is there a reason your workbook is .xlsm? Doesn't seem necessary to save in this format for the question asked. I won't be downloading this.

Comment: As I mentioned it contains a VBA code. I did not add any macros to it.
I will upload one w/o the VBA code

Comment: Are you sure that your locale use a dot `.` and not a comma `,` as decimal delimiter? In your question you have written `A1 = 317.84` and not `A1 = 317,84`.. If that is the case in your spreadsheet as well you might be working with strings and not numbers.

Comment: We use a comma as a delimiter in Israel - also my PC has US locale set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have [circular references](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-HP010066243.aspx) in `BX68`, `BW68`, `BU68`, `BS68`, `BR68`. Change in each of this cells `68` to `67`. Correct formulas:

1. BX68: `=SUM(BX65:BX67)`
2. BW68: `=SUM(BW65:BW67)`
3. BU68: `=SUM(BU65:BU67)`
4. BS68: `=SUM(BS65:BS67)`
5. BR68: `=SUM(BR65:BR67)`

A guide for finding circular references easly: http://blogs.mccombs.utexas.edu/the-most/2012/06/22/find-circular-references-in-excel/